# Creating Objects for the interface directly using new keyword

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface

The following code compiles successfully without any compilation errors but how can  we create Array(object) for Interface using new Keyword with the interface name.
 Objects can be created for the implementing class and can be referred by the interface like

```
interface MyInterface{}
class MyClass1 implements MyInterface{}
class MyClass2 implements MyInterface{}
class Test{ 
  MyInterface[] interfaceArray=new MyClass1[7];  //Valid reason
}
```

Now the other case is creating object for the Interface itself.

```
 interface MyInterface{}
class MyClass1 implements MyInterface{}
class MyClass2 implements MyInterface{}
class Test{ 
  MyInterface[] interfaceArray=new MyInterface[7];  /*instantiating interface   here, How is it possible?*/
}
```

Please explain the reason for the strange behaviour

Comment: You're not instantiating an interface here, you are instantiating an array type which just happens to have an interface as a component type.

Comment: @john, Thank you, can you explain in detail please

Comment: but new keyword returns an object when used so how is it possible to use new keyword with interface

Comment: Like I said, you're not using the `new` keyword with an interface. `MyInterface` is an `interface` but `MyInterface[]` is _not_. If you check the return of `MyInterface[].class.isInterface()` you'll  see that it returns `false`.

Comment: @Jorn,Thank you :)

Comment: You do not instantiate interfaces here. You create arrays.

Answer (score 0):

That is the right behavior. `MyInterface[] interfaceArray=new MyInterface[7];` **ONLY** instantiate an array length of `7` which will hold the items each one should be an instance of `MyInterface`.
After that, you are able to write `interfaceArray[0]=new MyInterface(){};`
And now you must implement your interface (see the curly brackets).
Probably, you misunderstanding based on a slightly ambiguous using operator `new` in Java. It is used to instantiate the classes (getting their instances) and declaring arrays (allocating memory for them).